# Defining a variable with a name that is kept in an other variable

Tags: common-lisp

I need to define a variable with a name contained in another variable.

The following code does not work and it uses `eval`, therefore not very good style.

```
(defvar symbol "zap")
(eval `(defvar ,symbol 100))
(print zap)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all -- are you sure you need to do this?

Now, with that out of the way --

```
(defvar *symbol-name* "zap")
(let ((symbol (intern *symbol-name*)))
  (proclaim `(special ,symbol))
  (setf (symbol-value symbol) 100))
(print |zap|)
```

Note that `|zap|` will normally need to be quoted with pipes, because `intern` is case-sensitive, while the default readtable upcases symbols by default.  So if you don't quote, as in `(print zap)`, that is interpreted as `(PRINT ZAP)`, with the wrong case for `zap`.  Alternatively, you can upcase the interned symbol, with `(intern (string-upcase *symbol-name*))`.

---

*Update after seeing what you're actually trying to do.*

You definitely don't want to be defining global variables for that.  A data structure that maps keys (A1...H4, etc) to numbers is what you want.  In this case, your keys can be symbols or strings.  And the data structure could be a hashtable, a plist or alist (among other choices).  For example, a string-keyed hashtable would look like:

```
(defvar *table* (make-hash-table :test #'equalp))
(setf (gethash "A1" *table*) 42)
(print (gethash "A1" *table*)) ==>  prints 42
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel. What I am trying to achive is to have 64 Variables with names "A1".."H8", that contain the values 21..98. A1=21,...,H1=28, A2=31,..,H2=38,....H8=98. So I started with (dolist (c '(a b c d e f g h i j)) (dolist (r '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)) (defvar ...))). Is there a better aproach for this task?

Comment: Yeah you definitely don't want to be defining a bunch of global variables for that (imagine what would happen if you actually use a variable called H1 at some point in the program).  Check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to use a hash table for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to do this, with global variables, I suspect that SET and SYMBOL-VALUE (and using symbols instead of strings) might do the trick. It definitely falls in the "hm, yes, you can do it that way, but I am not convinced it's the best way" territory, though.

However, you are most probably better off either using a hash-table or (skipping storage completely, if there's no need to mutate what A1 means further down the line) a function that parses the letter and digit apart and calculates the relevant value.

Comment: the reason why I considered this to be usefull is: The A1..H8 are inices into an array. This array has to work with indices 0..119 for reasons that arise from the application (chessboard). I thought it to be convenient to be able to say (setf (aref board a1) 'king) and so on. But I also see, that the global namespace might not be the right place for the field names. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use **SET**:

```
CL-USER 13 > (defvar *some-symbol* '*this-is-some-symbol*)
*SOME-SYMBOL*

CL-USER 14 > (set *some-symbol* 42)
42

CL-USER 15 > *this-is-some-symbol*
42
```

or if it is a string:

```
(setf (symbol-value (find-symbol some-symbol-name)) 42)
```

Comment: how could i forget that there is non only a "quoted set" (setq) but also the generic "set" instruction. I suspect that I am thinking little to complicated, sometimes. Thank you, Rainer!